# Wordpress/phpmyadmin access site issue

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm new to WordPress/PHPmyAdmin and looks like I'm having an issue with access phpmyadmin site.

Looks like I can access phpmyadmin site using http, but not when I use https. I get a browser username and password (not the phpmyadmin page) when using https. The wp-admin site works fine either way.

Apache logs show me the user is not found. So I not sure why the browser is asking for credentials.

We have to start force https on our sites. So this has become an issue.

Thank you 
Devon

Comment: So is your question **"How can I get the PHPMyAdmin screen available on HTTPS?"**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing a browser login that's different from your usual phpMyAdmin login page, it seems your web server has some other protections in place and is requiring a login separate from the phpMyAdmin authentication. Check your Apache configuration for the SSL side of things for some restrictions.

phpMyAdmin does have different authentication modes ("auth_type" in the configuration) which can present a form based login page, a browser popup, or no authentication at all — but it wouldn't change the mode based on whether you're using https or regular http, so it's definitely looking like an Apache configuration issue.